# Multiple Navigation Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble organizing the registration/login flow of my app. I currently have the storyboard entry point of the app pointing to a navigation controller. In `AppDelegate.m` if the user is **not logged in** have:

```
    SignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[SignUpViewController alloc] init];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:signUpViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This creates the 'sign up' navigation controller.

I have tried to pop this `SignUpViewController` along with the Navigation Controller to get to the initial screen of the app (the navigation controller initially pointed to in the storyboard), but I have not had any success.

Comment: Have you tried removing `SignUpViewController` by this code `[signUpViewController.view removeFromSuperview];`

Answer (score 1):

When you use storyboards (and therefore have a initial view controller there) what iOS is doing for you is to set the `window.rootViewController` to be the view controller with this *initial view controller flag*.

In your code you are **replacing** the root view controller for the `SignUpViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`  and that's why you cannot actually pop from it because there is no other view controller previously on the stack.

One solution could be to add a logic on the first view controller that identifies if the user is logged in and in case not you push (or present modally if you will) the `SignUpViewController`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You already set self.navController as the rootViewController of the window. To be able to accomplish what you want you could do one of these:

- Programmatically set the navigation controller initially pointed to in the storyboard as the rootViewController. Then present the SignupViewController as a modal.

or

- Present the SignupViewController (as a modal) from the Initial view controller in the storyboard instead of in the app delegate